# computer freezes while opening applications and popups

Tags: gnome, windows, 21.04

This problem come with all new windows and popups showing on screen, right after showing the computer freezes for one second but this is terrible while getting lots of notifications or while getting popups.

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 with Gnome 40.3 on two devices and they have the same issue, I have also tried disabling al the themes and extensions but the problem is still there, they use intel and amd gpu